# Access to OSGi bundle deployed on JBoss7.1 via https(SSL)

Tags: ssl, jboss, https, osgi

I have a simple java webapp(SSO-server) deployed on JBoss 7.1
JBoss configured to use SSL thrue 443 port, selfsignet cert and keystore

```
 <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="https" password="12345678" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/sso.keystore"/>
 </connector>
   ...
 <socket-binding name="https" port="443"/>
```

All work fine i can access to servlet(with "sso-service/auth" mapping) using

"https://localhost/sso-service/auth"

But now I separate my app into OSGi bundles (serviseApi, serviseImpl, web),

to register servlets i use "org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"

```
httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(context
    .getServiceReference(HttpService.class.getName()));

AuthenticationServlet authServlet = new AuthenticationServlet();

httpService.registerServlet(SSO_AUTH_URL, authServlet, null, null);
```

also i add this configuration to JBoss standalone.xml:

```
<socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8080"/>
```

when I deploy all bundles I get response from my servlets via http

"http://localhost:8080/sso-service/auth"

but when I try "https://localhost:443/sso-service/auth" I recive my selfsignet sert but have no unsver from servlets.
As I understand my servlets run only on "osgi-http"- 8080 port

So, have can I get https access to this bundle, what additional configs needed?